# Java Reflections library: find subclasses in package non recursively

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

Given the following snippet:

```
Set<Class<? extends MyClass>> allClasses = 
  new Reflections("mypackage").getSubTypesOf(MyClass.class);
```

The library recursively search for all the classes extending `MyClass` in the given package **and subpackages**. I need to do this in the given package only, i.e., not in the subpackages. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is brute force, but:

1) Get subclasses of MyClass. Put in a set.

2) Iterate over classes in the set; remove classes which belong to other packages (i.e. those for which _someClass.getPackage().equals(MyClass.class.getPackage()) is false)

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. This has nothing to do with subclasses, but subpackages.

Comment: Oh, sorry -- read that wrong.  But, you could still use a brute-force approach:  iterate over all the classes returned by getSubTypesOf and remove those for which (_someClass.getPackage().equals(MyClass.class.getPackage()) is false.

Comment: Update the answer and I'll accept. I ended up doing something along those line because of what seems to be [a bug in the filter](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/26).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the input filter (a Predicate), so that types in sub packages would not be scan:

```
new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().
    addUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("my.pack")).
    filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().
        include("my\\.pack\\..*\\.class").
        exclude("my\\.pack\\..*\\..*\\.class")));
```

And of course, you can always (post) filter the results, for example:

```
import static org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.*;

getAll(reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class), 
    withPattern(".*my\\.pack\\.(?!.*\\..*).*")); //ouch...
```

Comment: I tried a few combinations using filters but I think I have found [a bug](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/26) preventing this from being useful.